# Improving accuracy on a multi-class image classifiier

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch, classification, fast-ai

I am building a classifier using the Food-101 dataset. The dataset has predefined training and test sets, both labeled. It has a total of 101,000 images. I’m trying to build a classifier model with >=90% accuracy for top-1. I’m currently sitting at 75%. The training set was provided unclean. But now, I would like to know some of the ways I can improve my model and what are some of the things I’m doing wrong.

I’ve partitioned the train and test images into their respective folders. Here, I am using 0.2 of the training dataset to validate the learner by running 5 epochs.

```
np.random.seed(42)
data = ImageList.from_folder(path).split_by_rand_pct(valid_pct=0.2).label_from_re(pat=file_parse).transform(size=224).databunch()

top_1 = partial(top_k_accuracy, k=1)
learn = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet50, metrics=[accuracy, top_1], callback_fns=ShowGraph)
learn.fit_one_cycle(5)
```

```
epoch   train_loss  valid_loss  accuracy    top_k_accuracy  time
0       2.153797    1.710803    0.563498    0.563498    19:26
1       1.677590    1.388702    0.637096    0.637096    18:29
2       1.385577    1.227448    0.678746    0.678746    18:36
3       1.154080    1.141590    0.700924    0.700924    18:34
4       1.003366    1.124750    0.707063    0.707063    18:25
```

[image]

And here, I’m trying to find the learning rate. Pretty standard to how it was in the lectures:

```
learn.lr_find()
learn.recorder.plot(suggestion=True)
```

```
LR Finder is complete, type {learner_name}.recorder.plot() to see the graph.
Min numerical gradient: 1.32E-06
Min loss divided by 10: 6.31E-08
```

[image]

Using the learning rate of 1e-06 to run another 5 epochs. Saving it as stage-2

```
learn.fit_one_cycle(5, max_lr=slice(1.e-06))
learn.save('stage-2')
```

```
epoch   train_loss  valid_loss  accuracy    top_k_accuracy  time
0       0.940980    1.124032    0.705809    0.705809    18:18
1       0.989123    1.122873    0.706337    0.706337    18:24
2       0.963596    1.121615    0.706733    0.706733    18:38
3       0.975916    1.121084    0.707195    0.707195    18:27
4       0.978523    1.123260    0.706403    0.706403    17:04
```

[image]

Previously I ran 3 stages altogether but the model wasn’t improving beyond 0.706403 so I didn’t want to repeat it. Below is my confusion matrix. I apologize for the terrible resolution. Its the doing of Colab.

[image]

Since I’ve created an additional validation set, I decided to use the test set to validate the saved model of stage-2 to see how well it was performing:

```
path = '/content/food-101/images'
data_test = ImageList.from_folder(path).split_by_folder(train='train', valid='test').label_from_re(file_parse).transform(size=224).databunch()

learn.load('stage-2')
learn.validate(data_test.valid_dl)
```

This is the result:

```
[0.87199837, tensor(0.7584), tensor(0.7584)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Try augmentations like RandomHorizontalFlip, RandomResizedCrop,
  RandomRotate, Normalize etc from torchvision transforms. These always help a lot in classification problems.
- Label smoothing and/or Mixup precision training.
- Simply try using a more optimized architecture, like EfficientNet.
- Instead of OneCycle, a longer, more manual training approach may help. Try Stochastic Gradient Descent with a weight decay of 5e-4 and a Nesterov Momentum of 0.9. Use Warmup Training of around 1-3 epochs, and then regular training of around 200 epochs. You could set a manual learning rate schedule or cosine annealing or some other scheme. This entire method will consume a lot more time and effort than the usual onecycle training, and should be explored only if other methods don't show considerable gains.

Comment: The project specifies that I can only use ResNet50 or lower.  I am currently in the middle of label smoothing but could you tell me a little more about the augmentations?

Comment: RandomRotate, HorizontalFlip etc bring much more diversity to your training set, and directly affect its ability to generalize on test evaluation. Some augmentation is always necessary to achieve good accuracies on classification problems.